# Example of a utility function which yields inelastic demand function

Tags: reference-request, utility, consumer-theory, elasticity

I am looking for a example of a utility function which, when the utility maximisation problem is solved, results in an inelastic demand. The standard examples in textbooks always seem to have unitary elasticity.

In more detail, is it possible to find an example of a utility function $U(c)$ such that solving $\sup_c U(c)$ subject to $p c \leq m$ results in a consumption rule $c^*(p, m) \propto p^{-\alpha}$, with $\alpha < 1$?

References are always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we could get the demand function $c(p) = 1 - p$ (for $p\leq1$) that would be great, because then
$$
\epsilon(p) = \frac{\text{d}c(p)}{\text{d}p}\frac{p}{c(p)} = -\frac{p}{1-p}
$$
would run the gamut:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{p \searrow 0} \epsilon(p) & = \lim_{p \searrow 0}  \frac{-p}{1-p} = 0 \\
\\
\lim_{p \nearrow 1} \epsilon(p) & = \lim_{p \nearrow 1}  \frac{-p}{1-p} = -\infty,
\end{align*}
with demand being inelastic under $p=1/2$.

Good news! It is in fact possible to get this demand function from the utility function
$$
U(c,y) = c - \frac{c^2}{2} + y,
$$
where $y$ is the amount of money spent on other goods.

---

Could we get a demand function $c(p)$ where $\epsilon(p) = p^{\alpha}$, with $0 > \alpha > -1$ over the entire price range? Bad news :( 
Such a demand function would imply an infinite budget, since the expenditure on the good is
$$
c(p) \cdot p = p^{\alpha} \cdot p = p^{\alpha + 1}, 
$$
and since $ \alpha > -1$, we have
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} c(p) \cdot p = \lim_{p \to \infty} p^{\alpha + 1} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Does the utility function $U(c) = c - c^2/2$ have a name?

Comment: Hi! $U(c,y) = c - c^2/2 + y$ is *a* quasilinear utility function. I am unclear on what model you are using; $U(c) = c - c^2/2$ is a univariate utility function, it is not very meaningful in itself, without the model. You will get a different demand function if you are doing intertemporal decisions with this type of function.

Comment: Thanks, I am planning to use it in a stochastic control context - I was just looking for alternatives to power utility. Happy to give this one a whirl. Apparently this type of quadratic utility shows up everywhere in portfolio theory.

Comment: How would you modify your approach above for intertemporal decisions?

Comment: Hi! This is a very far leading and separate question. Please post it as a new question and give enough details to make an answer possible.